# Xbox One Controller Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, games

I've got some problems with my xbox one controller. My ubuntu does recognize that I have plugged in a xbox controller (lsusb and jstest show me the xbox controller) but it ignores every input and the xbox symbol on my controller stays dark. Now I do not have a clue what i should try next, is there anything I have to do so that my os will accept inputs from my controller? Did I miss some article about that problem or is it working fine for everyone than me?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the OP:

> After a bit of research I noticed that my kernel did not support xbox one controller so I installed 4.5.1 and everything works fine now.