# Gamepad working as a mouse (not desired behaviour)

Tags: drivers

My gamepad is working unexpectedly as a mouse once I connect it to the usb port.

It used to work fine; it's only recently that it has start to behave as a mouse.

Any hint on how to solve it? I don't know where to start.

Comment: What is the gamepad exact model?

Comment: Xbox 360 usb controller

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/791032/271