# Why isn't my Xbox One controller responding at all? (No light in LED, no events)

Tags: drivers, games, xbox-one

My Xbox One controller is an "@Play Wired Controler", which works without problems on my laptop's Windows partition.

Plugging it into Ubuntu running the `xpad` driver(0.4, installed as instructed in [How do I get an Xbox One controller to work with 16.04 (not Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam))) doesn't make the controller's LED flash at all, and the controller doesn't respond trying to play Super Meat Boy, or opening jstest-gtk.

Having compiled the latest stable version of `xboxdrv` as documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915568/installing-driver-for-xbox-powera-spectra-controller/996587#996587), I can get

```
➜  ~ sudo xboxdrv
xboxdrv 0.8.8 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ 
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmail.com> 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for 
details. 

Controller:        @Play - Wired Controller for Xbox One - Manette Avec Fil
Vendor/Product:    0e6f:02b2
USB Path:          002:014
Controller Type:   unknown


Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
  /dev/input/js0
  /dev/input/event13

Press Ctrl-C to quit, use '--silent' to suppress the event output
```

But I get no event-output pressing the buttons. Neither `js0` nor `event13` seem to give anything using `evtest`.

I am baffled and out of options. Can it be receiving too little power?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an Xbox One controller to work with 16.04 (not Steam)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam)

Answer (score 0):

## Upgrade your kernel

I had exactly the same symptoms. Controller seemed to be recognised, `xpad` was loaded, `/etc/dev/input/js0` was created, but pressing buttons on the controller had no effect at all through `evtest` or `jstest-gtk`.

I upgraded my kernel to version 4.13.0 (I was on version 4.4.0 before ; https://askubuntu.com/a/906014 suggests at least version 4.5.1) and it now works well (when connected by USB).

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the following command install the latest kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Disclaimer: be ready to return to an older kernel through GRUB if needed

Comment: Doing `uname -a` gives `4.13.0-32-generic`. Would it make sense to try and upgrade further?